# Add block to layout dynamically in event observer

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, event-observer

I want to know how to use layout.xml with event observer.

I want to show a message in footer when payment made successfully.

I know I have to use the event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

How to use controller or layout.xml with event observer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` is triggered right before the layout is rendered, so you can still manipulate it.

The observer only receives the order id as a parameter, so you have to get the layout via app model:

```
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
```

Now you can do your changes programmatically, like this:

```
$messageBlock = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'payment_message_block');
$messageBlock->setTemplate('payment_message.phtml');
$layout->getBlock('footer')->append($messageBlock);
```

---

If you use the `controller_action_layout_load_before` event, you can also load a custom layout handle like this, if on the success page:

```
if ($observer->getAction()->getFullActionName() === 'checkout_onepage_success') {
    $layout = $observer->getLayout();
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('custom_layout_handle');
}
```

which you can define in XML:

```
<layout>
  <custom_layout_handle>
     <reference name="footer">
       <block type="core/template" name="payment_message_block" template="payment_message.phtml" />
     </reference>
  </custom_layout_handle>
</layout>
```

---

**Update:** The footer block is cached, so we have to make sure that a different version is fetched from the cache if the message is present. For example:

```
$footer = $layout->getBlock('footer');
$footer->setCacheKey(sha1($footer->getCacheKey() . '-payment-message');
```

---

> how to pass genrated data to phtml file? which i am showing

Reference your block by name and use `setData()`. For example:

```
$block = $layout->getBlock('payment_message_block')->setData('messsage', 'Hello');
```

And in the template:

```
echo $this->getData('message');
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works for the footer block. It would work for almost any other block, but when the cache is enabled, the footer is cached and it might not display the message.

Comment: Good point @Marius, if possible I'd try to use `before_body_end` which is not cached

Comment: Yep, that should work.

Comment: If it must be in `footer` for design reasons, I added a solution that changes the cache key.

Comment: that is why i am also confused because in layout nothing mention related to observer. which i was find before submit question here

Comment: @fschmengler  can you please send exact solution. i m too new. Do you mean  i have to use refrence name="before_body_end" ?

Comment: as marius said footer is cached. can you guys tell me where can i find which block updates on cache enabled and which will not

Comment: @RahulChaurasia Yes, "before_body_end" instead of "footer". And to clarify, there is no specific relation between observers and layout, observers are just code, executed at certain events. Regarding how to find out which blocks are cached, this is going too far, it should be a separate question.

Comment: @fschmengler in your answer first type solution is working. i mean i want to load it form layout.xml. (from custom handle). Even my code is right because when i use another event(i.e. "controller_action_layout_load_before") its working.

Comment: @fschmengler in your answer first type solution is working but second type is not. i mean i want to load it form layout.xml. (from custom handle). Even my code is right because when i use another event(i.e. "controller_action_layout_load_before") second type is also working

Comment: i have 1 more problem related this. how to pass genrated data to phtml file?  which i am showing ?

Comment: @RahulChaurasia right, you have to add the handles to load before the layout is loaded, I didn't think about that. So use `controller_action_layout_load_before` and add a check if the current page is the success page. I'll update my answer