# Add third party tracking code to sales_quote_remove_item event

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, shopping-cart, sales, ecommerce-tracking

I am working on the process of integrating third party tracking code into Magento 1.9.3.3 and managed to add tracking for customer registration, Add to cart, Successful checkout.

But Remove an item from cart is not been able to trigger the tracking code. Please have a look on my code and let me know valuable suggestions.

My **config.xml** code:

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_remove_item>
        <observers>
            <sales_quote_remove_item_smartech>
                <class>smartech/observer</class>
                    <method>removeFromCartScript</method>
                </sales_quote_remove_item_smartech>
         </observers>
    </sales_quote_remove_item>
</events>
```

My **observer** code:

```
public function removeFromCartScript ($observer) {      
     $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();          
     $p_url = $item->getUrl();
     $p_id = $item->getId();
     $p_name = $item->getName();
     $p_qty = $item->getQty();
     $p_price = $item->getFinalPrice();      
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setProductFromShoppingCart('remove_from_cart');
     $removeProductVariable = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getProductFromShoppingCart();
     Mage::log("Session Variable: ".$removeProductVariable, null, "smartech.log");
}
```

and my **PHTML** code:

```
<?php    
    $removeProductVariable = Mage::getModel('core/session')->getProductFromCart();
    if($removeProductVariable === 'remove_from_cart') {
    echo "Remove from cart called"; 
    ?>
     <script>   
     //Following script need to be triggered with deleted product details respectively
     smartech('dispatch', 5, {
            "s^prurl": "<?php echo $p_url ?>",
            "i^prid": "<?php echo $p_id ?>",
            "s^prname": "<?php echo $p_name ?>",
            "i^prqt": "<?php echo $p_qty ?>",
            "f^prprice": "<?php echo number_format((float)$p_price, 2, '.', '')?>"
        }); 
    </script>   
    <?php   
    // Clear add_to_cart session variable:
    Mage::getModel('core/session')->unsProductFromCart();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

sales_quote_remove_item returns a Quote item object, so you'd need to load the quote first, before items. Psuedo code here for you;

```
public function removeFromCartScript($observer) {    
foreach ($observer->getEvent()->getProduct() as $item) {           
     $p_url = $item->getUrl();
     $p_id = $item->getId();
     $p_name = $item->getName();
     $p_qty = $item->getQty();
     $p_price = $item->getFinalPrice();      
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setProductFromShoppingCart('remove_from_cart');
     $removeProductVariable = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getProductFromShoppingCart();
     Mage::log("Session Variable: ".$removeProductVariable, null, "smartech.log");
}
}
```

Comment: I want to add the JS code in phtml code by using session variable, please let me know how to pass those product attribute values from observer to phtml file.

Comment: You'd need to add a block to the layout containing the code, and phtml that gives out the results. This may help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99150/add-block-to-layout-dynamically-in-event-observer